# Div not fading out - Chrome bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

This is the website that i'm working: [site](http://avellaneda.eu/real-people/)

My client is having a problem with the fading out of the photo info. I can't replicate the error even using the same browser version (chrome 33.0.1750).

This is the script i'm using to position the info div:

```
$('.realpeople-img').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('.realpeople-info').fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var offset = $('#fancybox-wrap').offset();
        /* $('.realpeople-info').css('top', offset.top + 30); */
        $('.realpeople-info').css('left', offset.left + 30);
    }, 100);
});
```

And this is inside the `$.fancybox.close = function() {`:

```
 $('.realpeople-info').fadeOut(1);
```

And this is what is happening to him:
(Looks like after he opens and close every image the info stays on the screen without fading out)

[image]

Does someone here has the same problem? any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Works fine for me: Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 m

Comment: what happened to screenshots?

Comment: @AndrewBrown Lol... one word: Clients

Comment: ahh, of course. too funny.

Answer (score 1):

1 is not 1 second, the value assigns in millisecond so you might be trying to apply 1 second and for this set 1000. 1000ms = 1s

```
$('.realpeople-info').fadeOut(1000);
```